# Why MS Access pop up form doesn't regain focus after switching apps with Alt-Tab?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

I have an Access 2016 application that opens a pop-up form when user double-clicks on a record in a datasheet form. That's meant to be a 'detail form' showing all fields in record (datasheet shows only a few).  Now, while editing data on popup form, I switch to another app (say Notepad) to copy some text from there or simply check some other thing. I then switch back to Access app by  applying Alt-Tab. However, now focus is over datasheet form, instead of pop up form it was when I first switched to Notepad.

Can anyone please help on understanding why this happens? Ultimately I want to return focus over popup form whenever I switch back from any other app by using Alt-Tab, i.e., maybe by detecting in VBA when Access ***application*** gets focus back so I can set focus on desired form. I've read some suggestions about using some Windows API function but no detailed examples on that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When showing the form, make it modal.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay braX. I'd rather not do that as user should be able to open some other form (other menu option) while editing record.

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour. For me, the pop-up stays in front.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, it stays in front even if it's not modal?

Comment: Yes. And I've never seen any other behaviour.

Comment: I've seen this behavior before in one of my dbs and the only way I have found to rectify it is to repeatedly alt-tab until your popup is in front again.